Weird expression: 〇・一秒
I have found this phrase in a book: 余裕なんて本当に〇・一秒もない。
I understand the meaning of the sentence but I have never seen that 〇・thing ever before.
I thought it could mean 0.1, so the whole thing would become something like "not even one tenth of a second" but it feels weird that they'd decide to use ◯.

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95895/7810

If you saw it in a vertical text, 〇 is the (or at least a) correct way to write zero, as explained in here.

縦書きの場合、番地などの住所は漢数字で記載し、数字の「0」は「〇」を使います

Even if the text is horizontal, it is possible 〇・一 slips into it due to the vertical convention as mentioned in here (speaking about newspaper, but it can happen in general).

The text was indeed vertical, thank you.
